The 7th chord as a gateway/bridge to?
Some time ago, I wrote a 12 bar chord loop, based on a strange use of the 7th chord:
Question on music.se
I noticed you can extend that schema (Bm, D, F#,A) somewhat, but would It loop through all the 12 notes?
Looks like to me...
I could add a picture of my notes, but it's over 2mb... Sorry

Yes, the roots of the chords would touch every key. Each pair of chord roots are a major third and minor third apart, or vice versa. A major third and minor third combined make a perfect fifth (e.g., Bm F# or D A from the given example), so the progression would eventually complete the circle of fifths.

          At this point, all 12 keys have been touched
                                                     v
B D F# A C# E G# B D# F# A#/Bb Db/C# F Ab/G# C Eb/D# G Bb D F A C E G B
^   ^    ^    ^    ^     ^           ^       ^       ^    ^   ^   ^   ^
1   2    3    4    5     6           7       8       9    10  11  12  1
                                                                      ^
                                           Circle fifths completed here


Thx. Does this have a name?

@ccampisano Not that I know of, aside from being an elaboration of the circle of fifths.

Wells, a fifth it's 7 semitones, here we're doing 4+3 or 3+4, so the thirds are in too, Major or minor as appropriate, right?

@ccampisano Right. That’s the point my post is making.
